# Missing configuration setting in configuration manager

Tags: visual-studio, configurationmanager

I often create custom build configurations in my solution's Configuration Manager.  When I include previously created projects into the solution they do not automatically include these new configurations.  The only way I have found to back fill these projects with the appropriate configuration settings is to manually edit the project file.

Is there a way to force all projects in a solution to all use the same set of Configuration Manager configurations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found that removing all the configurations and than adding them back in again fixes all the projects in the solution

Comment: Just removing and re-adding the broken configuration works as well. Say if one of the projects is missing Test configuration removing and adding it back in fixes the issue.

Comment: @TarasAlenin How do you do this easily without reconfiguring them manually?

Answer (score 3):

The [VS2010 "Export Template Wizard" extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24) will work for this situation. You will have to create a project and set up all of your configuruations, files, etc. Then export it as a Template. When you start a new project you can select your new template and the settings in the Configuration Manager will carry over. I created a simple test project and this worked. This will not account for any projects that you have already created.

[This blog post by DevGuy](http://www.devguy.org/2011/11/part-1-creating-visual-studio-2010-web.html) has a walk through with pictures on the process.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and here is how I fixed it.

First close Visual Studio and find the project guid from new projects. Your can do this by looking in your `.csproj` file. Then open the solution file in a text editor like Notepad++.

In the solution file, find the section called `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution`.

Each of your projects will have a listing there with the configuration. You will notice that your new projects *likely already have settings for your configurations*, **BUT** they will be set to **DEBUG** or **RELEASE** as shown in the example below.

```
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Staging|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Staging|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Live|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Live|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
```

To fix this, change the `Debug|Any CPU` to be instead your configuration. So in my example above my settings will become the following:

```
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Staging|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Staging|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Staging|Any CPU.Build.0 = Staging|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Live|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Live|Any CPU
{2E6B7D61-640E-4878-BE6D-7CD705AB9A6A}.Live|Any CPU.Build.0 = Live|Any CPU
```

Save the changes and then relaunch Visual Studio and open your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [Visual Studio macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that does this for you. Bind it to a menu button and you have a one-click way to add these configurations to a project.